# Generate absolute URL with specific scheme in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to generate an absolute URL with a specific scheme (https) in a Symfony2 controller. All the solutions I found point me to [configure the targeted route so that it *requires* that scheme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html). But I need the route to remain accessible in http, so I can't set it to require https (in which case http requests are redirected to the corresponding https URL).

Is there a way to generate an URL with, in the scope of that URL generation only, a specific scheme?

I saw that using the `'network'` keyword generates a "network path"-style URL, which looks like "//example.com/dir/file"; so maybe I can simply do

```
'https:' . $this->generateUrl($routeName, $parameters, 'network')
```

But I don't know if this will be robust enough to any route or request context.

*UPDATE: after investigation in the URL generation code, this "network path" workaround seems fully robust. A network path is generated exactly as an absolute URL, without a scheme before the "//".*

Comment: Looks like an robust workaround you still keep your benefit that Symfony can generate an Url based on your Route config.You can also generate an absolute Url and str_replace the http: with https: this way you dont remove the www subdomain from your domain

Comment: @RaymondNijland, from simple tests it seems a subdomain (like www) is correctly included in generated "network path" URLs. Still, I don't know _for sure_ if these URLs are always the same as the corresponding absolute URL simply without the scheme before `//`, or if there could be specific scenarios where the results would differ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the code or documentation, currently you cannot do that within the generateUrl method. So your "hackish" solution is still the best, but as @RaymondNijland commented you are better off with `str_replace`:

```
$url = str_replace('http:', 'https:', $this->generateUrl($routeName, $parameters));
```

If you want to make sure it's changed only at the beginning of the string, you can write:

```
$url = preg_replace('/^http:/', 'https:', $this->generateUrl($routeName, $parameters));
```

No, the colon (`:`) has no special meaning in the regex so you don't have to escape it.

Comment: If OP decides to go for a string manipulation based solution, this is really nice way to do it :)

Comment: Yes, the regex version seems the best if we are to do it with string manipulations. The "one occurrence only" could be fooled by the fact that in some contexts, the generated URL might already be in https, in which case the string replacement could mess something else further in the URL.

Comment: Answer accepted, but to me the non-regex versions should be avoided, as they can mess the rest of the URL.
So in the end, for me it's either the "network path" workaround (cleaner), or the regex string manipulation (easier to understand when reading the code, as it uses more common mechanisms).

Comment: I agree that the `preg_replace` solution sounds like the best for the job. Hopefully this answer will be useful to others, too.

Comment: I don't know why would you replace it, when they already have ` UrlGeneratorInterface::NETWORK_PATH` to remove http for you.

Comment: FYI: you can't limit how often `str_replace` replaces. The fourth parameter is for passing the reference of a count variable.

Comment: @AWessel thank you for finding this. Fixed by removing the wrong part of the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Best way to go with this

```
$url = 'https:'.$this->generateUrl($routeName, $parameters, UrlGeneratorInterface::NETWORK_PATH)
```

Answer (score 3):

With default `UrlGenerator`, I don't think that is possible, **if you don't want** to mess with strings.

You could make your own `HttpsUrlGenerator extends UrlGenerator` introducting one slight change:

Within method `generate()`, instead of:

```
return $this->doGenerate(
    $compiledRoute->getVariables(), 
    $route->getDefaults(), 
    $route->getRequirements(), 
    $compiledRoute->getTokens(), 
    $parameters, 
    $name, 
    $referenceType, 
    $compiledRoute->getHostTokens(), 
    $route->getSchemes() 
);
```

You could do:

```
return $this->doGenerate(
    $compiledRoute->getVariables(), 
    $route->getDefaults(), 
    $route->getRequirements(), 
    $compiledRoute->getTokens(), 
    $parameters, 
    $name, 
    $referenceType, 
    $compiledRoute->getHostTokens(), 
    ['https']
);
```

As you can see, `$route->getSchemes()` gets pumped into `doGenerate()` based on the route settings (the tutorial link you provided above).

You could even go further and externalize this schema array and supply it via `__construct`.

Hope this helps a bit ;)

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand it, that solution would result in all absolute URLs being generated in https, which is not desired. I could modify further that `HttpsUrlGenerator` to add another parameter to apply a specific scheme or not, but then it seems like I would also have to extend the rest of the stack (`Router`, `Controller`). A bit tedious. Should work, though.

Comment: Yes, that is all true. Although, I thought that you actually wanted to generate `https` URLs only... my mistake...